# Unable to call method in component from d3.call()

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, d3.js

I'm using D3 to drag and drop links like so:

```
.call(d3.drag()
  .on("start", linkDragStart)
  .on("drag", linkDragging)
  .on("end", linkDragEnd));
```

Now I removed this function from inside the method and placed it as a separate method itself. So I change the above code to:

```
.call(d3.drag()
  .on("start", linkDragStart)
  .on("drag", linkDragging)
  .on("end", this.linkDragEnd));
```

The method is being called. Problem is, when is use the this keyword on inside the `linkDragEnd` method, it is getting referred to the d3-path on which the method is being called. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: If you don't need a reference to the path in the event listener you could use `this.linkDragEnd.bind(this)`.

Comment: it works!!! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible solutions. First, as suggested in the comments, is to use `bind`, i.e., instead of directly using the method `this.linkDragEnd`, use its bound version:

```
.call(d3.drag()
                .on("start", linkDragStart)
                .on("drag", linkDragging)
                .on("end", this.linkDragEnd.bind(this));
```

Another possibility is when you target modern JavaScript (ES6 at least) or use some transpiler (TypeScript, as suggested by tags, will suffice). Then, you can define this method not as true method, but as property, whose value is an arrow function:

```
linkDragEnd = (/* arguments here */) => {
    /* function body here */
}
```

Since the arrow functions have different behavior of `this`, they can be used as callbacks without explicit binding, as long as they refer to the object they are created in.